# JQuery slideToggle a list inside a list

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a table which has multiple rows. Within the rows are row options:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="rowOptions">
    <li>
        <img src="/images/navigation/arrow.png">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:updateRow(data)">Update</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:deleteRow(data);">Remove Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:archiveRow(data);">Archive Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Originally, the inner ul displays on hover but we want the options to appear only if the img is clicked. So far, I tried:

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click','.rowOptions img', function () {
    $('.rowOptions li ul').slideToggle();
});
```

The code works quite well on achieving the task of displaying the inner list except that it displays the inner list for all rows instead of the row being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use source of event using `$(this)`

```
$(document).on('click','.rowOptions img', function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Oh my god. That worked like charm! Thank you! Sorry I couldn't up your answer (I have so little reputation).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.rowOptions img', function () {
   $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try pointing out to the sub list inside the main menu list and toggle.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="rowOptions">
<li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_100/tree_root.jpg">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:updateRow(data)">Update</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:deleteRow(data);">Remove Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:archiveRow(data);">Archive Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
     <li>
    <img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_100/tree_root.jpg">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:updateRow(data)">Update</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:deleteRow(data);">Remove Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:archiveRow(data);">Archive Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.rowOptions img', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/p7v8p/3/

Happy Coding :)